# facebook application :comment plugin: moderator menu fb:app_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi i can't get this line to work:

> `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="ID_APP"/>`

My facebook application is public , but even with that i cant get the comments to appear on the dashboard or get the moderator menu appear on the app.
NB: I did put this line on the head.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Have you placed this meta tag under the URL(s) that you are pointing the comments plugin to? Did you refresh the FB cache of those URLs after you added the tag (via debug tool, or by triggering a re-scrape via API)?

Comment: just to eleminate the doubt , im working with a clean page juste some text and the plugin no other scripts , so its just this meta on the head with the title, and yes i alresdy cleaned the cach and refreshed all my browsers , but without a result

Comment: Several people have asked about this in the last few hours, here and in the FB developers group – so I’d assume it is probably a current bug. Go see if anything like that has already been reported recently, and if not, file your own report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: just got it working but this time all the comments are showing and in public mode while the settings is on closed which mean all the comments are supposed to stay hidden until review

Comment: @CBroe has this issue/bug become obsolete / No Repro?